# How do I get histogram with count in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We are trying to generate histogram in [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) using [Histogram aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html)

We are monitoring our API performance with ElasticSearch. A sample set of documents that we store are

```
{"name": "GET /login", "avg":2.2, "count": 5}
{"name": "GET /login", "avg":1.5, "count": 3}
{"name": "GET /login", "avg":6.9, "count": 1}
{"name": "GET /login", "avg":3.1, "count": 1}
```

Where

- `count` is number of `GET /login` web requests coming to our server for a specific time period.
- `avg` is average response time.

**Histogram Issue**

When I run histogram for `GET /login` alone, with interval of `1 second`, I get

```
 1-2 seconds - 1
 2-3 seconds - 1
 3-4 seconds - 1
 5-6 seconds - 1
```

However, what we are doing is, we are only storing the average with the count (to save space and not duplicate the records). But in reality, what we would like to get is

```
 1-2 seconds - 3
 2-3 seconds - 5
 3-4 seconds - 1
 5-6 seconds - 1
```

Mapping for our current `hist` index

```
PUT hist/_mapping/t
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "avg": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "count": {
      "type": "long"
    }
  }
}
```

We uses following query to get histogram.

```
GET /hist/t/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "avgs": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "avg",
        "interval": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Percentile Issue**

The same problem appears for percentile as well.

`1.5, 2.2, 3.1, 6.9` - The `75th percentile` is reported as `3.1` second. 
`1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 3.1, 6.9` - The real `75th percentile`is `2.2` seconds

We uses following query to get percentile.

```
GET /hist/t/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "avgs": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "avg"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I do it in elastic search?

Comment: The documents you're storing are already pretty similar to the answer you'd like to get. Can you show what query you're running now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're getting now is the document count for each histogram bucket. You can add one `sum` sub-aggregation on the `count` field and you should get what you expect. Try this:

```
POST /hist/t/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "avgs": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "avg",
        "interval": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_of_count": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "count"
          }
        },
        "perc_of_count": {
          "percentiles": {
            "field": "count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It works great. Awesome. Can you also give the query for percentile with count?

Comment: Cool, you can add another sub-aggregation using the [`percentiles` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-aggregation.html)

Comment: It will be great if you put percentile query in your answer. I updated my question for percentile too.

Comment: I've added the `percentiles` aggregation

Comment: If we use the above percentile query, the average is taken as only one doc. We would like the `avg` to be considered as "n" docs, with the "n" coming from the `count` field

Comment: I updated question about our percentile issue too. Can you give us query to solve it?

Comment: I have posted separate question for percentile. Can you please answer it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466925/how-do-i-get-percentiles-with-count-in-elasticsearch