# How do I get percentiles with count in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We are trying to generate Percentiles in [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) using [Percentiles aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-aggregation.html)

We are monitoring our API performance with ElasticSearch. A sample set of documents that we store are

```
{"name": "GET /login", "avg":2.2, "count": 5}
{"name": "GET /login", "avg":1.5, "count": 3}
{"name": "GET /login", "avg":6.9, "count": 1}
{"name": "GET /login", "avg":3.1, "count": 1}
```

Where

- `count` is number of `GET /login` web requests coming to our server for a specific time period.
- `avg` is average response time.

We uses following query to get percentile.

```
GET /hist/t/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "avg_time_percentile": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "avg",
         "percents" : [75, 95, 99] 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We get following response

```
"avg_time_percentile": {
  "values": {
    "75.0": 3.75,
    "95.0": 5.549999999999999,
    "99.0": 5.909999999999999
  }
```

However, what we want is:

```
"avg_time_percentile": {
  "values": {
    "75.0": 2,
    "95.0": 4.349999999999998,
    "99.0": 5.670000000000002
  }
```

The reason for the incorrect value is, it is taking for e.g. `2.2` as only in one record. But the count is `5` and it should be considered 5 times.

How do I do it in ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `field` you can use `script` in order to combine several fields together and run the percentiles on those new values

```
POST /hist/t/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "avg_time_percentile": {
      "percentiles": {
         "script": {
            "inline": "doc.avg.value * doc.count.value"
         },
         "percents" : [75, 95, 99] 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Executing your code, shows the percentile as

`
  "aggregations": {
    "avg_time_percentile": {
      "values": {
        "75.0": 7,
        "95.0": 9.399999999999999,
        "99.0": 9.879999999999999
      }
    }
  }`
I suppose, it is multiplying the `avg*count` and takes it as one value. Instead, it should take 2.2 as 5 different values. The expected `75th` percentile is 2

Comment: Then divide instead of multiply ?

Comment: I assume the question is, if each record is added individually, then the percentile output is different. For e.g. from the above records, if 2.2 is added 5 times, 1.5 is added 3 times, 6.9 once and 3.1 once, then the percentile is different. And whether that is possible without duplicating the records, but having a count variable that represents the number of duplicate records that should have been.

Comment: Yes, indeed, you have pre-aggregated the data into documents and now you're trying to aggregate it again, that's not going to work. You should have created five documents (one for each occurence) instead of one with count 5, otherwise you're biasing the whole computation. Doing these computations os the whole point of leveraging ES aggregations in the first place.